# NeoVim stopped working correctly: multiple distributions show same errors

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

I was writing some code. Everything was working fine, and at some point syntax
highlighting broke. When a file loads at first everything is ok. Then after about
10 seconds the highlighting changes.

Also nvim_lsp does not seem to work properly anymore, it takes ages before
everything is loaded. In rust if I want to fill the match arms with code actions
it adds the arms but 5 lines above where its suppose to and replaces a macro
entry; when the macro is removed it inserts fine in the right place. I took a
random config from someones github https://github.com/rsdlt to see if it was my
config or if this was in general broken. It also seems to happen with that
config, same problem, so I tried a few others and same problem.

I'm running arch linux, bob for neovim version management, NeoVim 0.9.x.
I tried multiple versions and the problem still persists.

Comment: I'm afraid your question lack some precision to allow others to help you. Furthermore it looks more like a bug report for Neovim 0.9 than a question on Vim/vi. To help you we would need a minimum configuration and the steps to reproduce the problem. But as said I suppose with this you should first post it as a bug report to Neovim :-/